# /0000/0000 search present when starting NeoVim in Mintty

Tags: neovim, cygwin

When I start the Windows-native NeoVim (with an empty `init.vim`) in a Mintty terminal for Cygwin (which sadly doesn't have its own NeoVim), a search is already present:
[image: NVim with preset search for 0000/0000 after start]

Otherwise it works.

And the Powershell NeoVim doesn't have this problem.

It's a strange combination, yes, but perhaps anyone knows a way to fix this? Aside from compiling NeoVim natively for Cygwin.

Comment: have you tried using `nvim --clean`

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I tried it and the problem persists

Comment: If this persists with `--clean` and other "clean" configurations, I would report a bug.